# IF THEN + 1 To Specific row/column?

Tags: mysql

So I've been working on a new project. I understand how to update a certain rows column value:

```
UPDATE PlayerInfo SET GearLevel = GearLevel +1 WHERE UID = "76561198008596823" ;
```

But I want to add some checks in it.

In Words.

> IF UID = "76561198008596823" AND BankMoney = 25000000 AND GearLevel =
>   15 THEN GearLevel + 1 AND BankMoney - 15000000

So I tested with:

```
UPDATE PlayerInfo SET GearLevel =
CASE WHEN GearLevel = 15 THEN GearLevel +1
Else
0
END ;
```

But this just added 1 to all values in the column that was at 15.

How can I add the checks to the CASE and also subtract BankMoney? Or is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not need to use a `CASE` expression here:

```
UPDATE PlayerInfo
SET
    GearLevel = GearLevel + 1,
    BankMoney = BankMoney - 15000000
WHERE
    UID = '76561198008596823' AND
    BankMoney = 25000000 AND
    GearLevel = 15;
```

A `CASE` expression would be needed if you wanted to update *every* record with some value.  Then, its logic would let you carefully decide which records get updated.  But if you only want to target accounts with the three conditions you gave us (`UID=7656...`, `BankMoney=2500000` and `GearLevel=15`), then you may just add this directly to the `WHERE` clause.